# convert a xlsm file from xlrd to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I want to know if is there a simple way to get a dataframe from a xlsm file, I tried just pandas with pd.Excelfile, but it doesn't read the data correctly

so... for now I have this:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

cartera_improd = xlrd.open_workbook("CARTERA IMPRODUCTIVA - FORMATOV1.xlsm")
base_ici = cartera_improd.sheet_by_name("BASE ICI")
print (base_ici.row_values(1))
print (base_ici.nrows)
data_ici = list()
for i in range(base_ici.nrows): 
    data_ici.append(base_ici.row_values(i))   
data_ici = pd.DataFrame(data_ici)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a xlsm file you just have to use :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('CARTERA IMPRODUCTIVA - FORMATOV1.xlsm')

print(df.head())
```

Comment: when I use: df=pd.read_excel(ruta+'CARTERA IMPRODUCTIVA - FORMATOV1.xlsm', sheet_names="BASE ICI") it just show me the first sheet of the file, not the one named "BASE ICI"

Comment: It's sheet_name not sheet_names.
Then I don't understand what is ruta there.

Anyway, read this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html